# How to skip converting element text

Tags: javascript, html

i want output text oldnames not changes if user insert text 'false'

for example:

user input text "false toni" in textbox.

and i want output still "false toni"

why my code still changes text "toni" with "rina"?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 String.prototype.replaceArr = function(find, replace) {
                var replaceString = this;
                var regex;
                for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
                    regex = new RegExp(find[i], "g");
                    replaceString = replaceString.replace(regex, replace[i]);
                }
                return replaceString;
            }

            function test() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
                var oldNames = ['toni','rian'];
    var newNames = ['rina','susi'];
    if (oldNames== 'false ' + oldNames){
                document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = x.replaceArr(oldNames, oldNames);
    }else{
    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = x.replaceArr(oldNames, newNames);
    }
            }
 </script>   
 <body>
 ENTER TEXT: <br>
 <textarea name="kata_cari" id="myText" style="width:100%; height:100px;"></textarea>
    <br>
 <input type="button" onclick="test();" value="Check!">
 <br>
 <p id="check"></p>
 </body>
```

UPDATE:

Improve the question:
Trying enter text "My name is rian and my name is false toni" .

Posible to make output "rian" still change to "susi"?

Comment: what you expect to do with that code?    var oldNames = ['toni','rian'];
    var newNames = ['rina','susi'];
    if (oldNames== 'false ' + oldNames){

Comment: replace the code if (oldNames== 'false ' + oldNames) with if (x.includes('false')) then it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use includes `x.includes(value)` to check whether the text area value contains a word that you want to replace . if it contains false then your oldnames not get changed.

If you are using IE then use `x.indexOf(value)>0` instead of `x.includes(value)`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  String.prototype.replaceArr = function(find, replace) {
    var replaceString = this;
    var regex;
    for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
      regex = new RegExp(find[i], "g");
      replaceString = replaceString.replace(regex, replace);
    }
    return replaceString;
  }

  function test() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    var oldNames = ['toni', 'rian'];
    var newNames = ['rina', 'susi'];
    oldNames.forEach(function(value, index) {
      /*if (x.includes('false '+value)){
      var oldNames1=['false '+value];
      x =  x.replaceArr(oldNames1, oldNames1);
     }*/
      if (x.includes(value)) {
        var oldNames1 = [value];

        x = x.replaceArr(oldNames1, newNames[index]);

        newNames1 = ['false ' + newNames[index]];
        oldNames1 = ['false ' + value];

        x = x.replaceArr(newNames1, oldNames1);


      }
    });
    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = x;
  }
</script>

<body>
  ENTER TEXT:
  <br>
  <textarea name="kata_cari" id="myText" style="width:100%; height:100px;"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="test();" value="Check!">
  <br>
  <p id="check"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much.. i will close this with ur answer

Comment: Sir. if trying enter text "My name is rian and my name is fake toni" .
Posible to make output "rian" still change to "susi"? .

Comment: actually toni is the oldename and rina is the new name for toni, and rian is the oldname and susi is the newname for rian . if you enter text without the word false then all the oldname will get changed to new name. As per your comment its working fine

Comment: don't use 'fake' , use false

Comment: ups sorry i mean "false" . Example :  enter text  "my name rian and false toni" .
Can i make output "my name susi and false toni" ?

Comment: I have updated , please refer the code and let me know whether its working or not.

Comment: 1000x thanks! code working good, but if enter text "my name toni and false toni" . the output "my name 'toni'  and false toni" .  why text "toni"(without false) can't change with rina?

Comment: write all the possibilities that you want to convert from old to new names , this will help for me to form the logic

Comment: I have update the code pls look into it.. you need to compare all the probabilities to form the logic for your requirement.

Comment: Super! Thankyou so much for help me.  I will learn more javascript.. :) ,

I will close this question now.

Answer (score 1):

You false checking condition is wrong, you can do it using `substr`:

```
if (x.substr(0, 6) === 'false ') {
    // The string starts with false
} else {
}
```

You can find more details on the substr from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

UPDATE: As mentioned in the comment same can be done via `startsWith` and this is a **better** approach.

```
if (x.startsWith('false ')) {
    // The string starts with false
} else {
}
```

Comment: Use `.search()` if the position of `'false'` does not matter

Comment: Use `startsWith`.

Comment: thanks.. its  work.. 
can u give me link for learning this condition?

Comment: trying enter "my name false toni" .
Why 'toni' still change with rina?

Comment: Sir . I choose use x.includes('false') if trying enter text "I have two name rian with false toni" . Posible to make output "I have two name susi with false toni" ? . Can make "rian" still change to "susi" ?

Answer (score 1):

try this. **Compare array values instead of array.**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 String.prototype.replaceArr = function(find, replace) {
                var replaceString = this;
                var regex;
                for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
                    regex = new RegExp(find[i], "g");
                    replaceString = replaceString.replace(regex, replace[i]);
                }
                return replaceString;
            }

            function test() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
                var oldNames = ['toni','rian'];
    var newNames = ['rina','susi'];
    if (x.indexOf('false') > -1 ){
                document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = x.replaceArr(oldNames, oldNames);
    }else{
    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = x.replaceArr(oldNames, newNames);
    }
            }
 </script>   
 <body>
 ENTER TEXT: <br>
 <textarea name="kata_cari" id="myText" style="width:100%; height:100px;"></textarea>
    <br>
 <input type="button" onclick="test();" value="Check!">
 <br>
 <p id="check"></p>
 </body>
```

Comment: trying enter "my name false toni" .
Why 'toni' still change with rina?

Comment: @jack.D What exactly op you want?? If it contains false inside string it does't change??? I just updated Code.. You can check now.

Comment: Sir . I choose use `x.includes('false')` if trying enter text "I have two name rian with false toni" . Posible to make output "I have two name susi with false toni" ?  , Can make  "rian" still change to "susi" ?